# Define beginning and ending of chapter

Tags: libreoffice

I'm creating (trying) a 'Table of Contents' for each chapter of a libreoffice writer document. I know that I can define a Table of Contents and set it to Chapter, so it won't take the entire document, just the current chapter.

The problem with this, is that **I don't know where a chapter started and where it ends**. Every time that I read help or another related question, it is so strongly related to other subjects (like outline numbering and text styles) that I can't differentiate those concepts.

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking, but I'm not quite sure. Are you saying that you want to generate a separate table of contents for each chapter?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the chapters are defined by level 1 headings. So, if you insert a ToC after a level 1 heading and select "Create for -> Chapter", the ToC will list all headings below the "current" level 1 heading.